# How to check if a user that is in Azure Active Directory belongs to a specific group membership?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I was able to query the the active directory on Azure and bring the user information such as name, country, department, ... etc.

However, I would like to know the group that the user who logged in belongs to. The function that I am using to bring a user's info is like the following:

```
public IUser GetUserData()
{
    string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
    string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

    Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceId);
    Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantID);
    ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot,
            async () => await GetTokenForApplication());

    // use the token for querying the graph to get the user details
    IUser user = activeDirectoryClient.Users
        .Where(u => u.ObjectId.Equals(userObjectID))
        .ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.ToList().First();

    return user;
}
```

I tried to use 'activeDirectoryClient' variable that is inside GetUserData method to check if a user is a member of a group like the following:

```
bool d = activeDirectoryClient.IsMemberOfAsync("group1", userObjectID).Result.Value;
```

However, it did not work!!

I also found this solution [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/blob/master/GraphConsoleAppV3/GraphRequests.cs), took it, and customized it like the following:

```
public async Task<IList<String>> GetGroups(IUser user)
        {
            IList<String> groupMembership = new List<String>();

            var userFetcher = (IUserFetcher)user;

            IPagedCollection<IDirectoryObject> pagedCollection = await userFetcher.MemberOf.ExecuteAsync();
            do
            {
                List<IDirectoryObject> directoryObjects = pagedCollection.CurrentPage.ToList();
                foreach (IDirectoryObject directoryObject in directoryObjects)
                {
                    if (directoryObject is Group)
                    {
                        var group = directoryObject as Group;
                        groupMembership.Add(group.DisplayName);
                        test.Text += group.DisplayName;
                    }
                }
                pagedCollection = await pagedCollection.GetNextPageAsync();
            } while (pagedCollection != null);


            return groupMembership;
        }
```

I am using global variables that are stored in my web.config file

```
 private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientID"];
 private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
 private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
 private static string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";
```

How can I check if 'user' has a group called 'group1'

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **IUserFetcher.Memberof**.

```
        ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot,
                async () => await GetTokenForApplication());


        IList<string> groupMembership = new List<string>();
        IUser user = activeDirectoryClient.Users.Where(u => u.ObjectId.Equals(userObjectID)).ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.ToList().First();
        var userFetcher = (IUserFetcher)user;

        IPagedCollection<IDirectoryObject> pagedCollection = userFetcher.MemberOf.ExecuteAsync().Result;
        do
        {
            List<IDirectoryObject> directoryObjects = pagedCollection.CurrentPage.ToList();
            foreach (IDirectoryObject directoryObject in directoryObjects)
            {
                if (directoryObject is Group)
                {
                    var group = directoryObject as Group;
                    groupMembership.Add(group.DisplayName);
                }
            }
            pagedCollection = pagedCollection.GetNextPageAsync().Result;
        } while (pagedCollection != null);
```

Comment: I saw this code here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/blob/master/GraphConsoleAppV3/GraphRequests.cs and I tried to call this function but it is giving me an exception

Comment: ahh.. I did not notice something in your answer .. it worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So the Graph API has `isMemberOf`which you can query to check if a user is a member of a specific group. Reference link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#isMemberOf

Comment: I found this link actually, but I am wondering of how to query the Graph API. Do you mean creating a variable called 'groupObject' like the one 'userObject' that I have?

Comment: why the 'user' variable doesn't have isMemberOf property?

Comment: http://graph255.rssing.com/chan-13124084/all_p2.html; https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/security-and-compliance/azure-active-directory-part-4-group-claims/; so probably like `activeDirectoryClient.isMemberOf(groupid,userid)`

Comment: I saw activeDirectoryClient.IsMemberOfAsync() but I don't know how to get the groupid and userid

Comment: well, you can query graph API to get those ;)